# Can Dapper's support for IEnumerables simplify an INSERT INTO SELECT?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

I'm trying to use Dapper's support for IEnumerable parameter objects to perform an INSERT INTO, but am running into trouble.

My INSERT statement is actually based on a SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO [tbl] ([col1], [col2], [col3])
OUTPUT Inserted.[id]
SELECT [col1] - 1, [col2] + 1, @newVal
FROM [tbl]
WHERE [id] IN @id AND [col1] > 1
```

I'm trying to use `Query<T>()` as follows:

```
int[] ids = ...;
var sql = @"INSERT INTO ..."; // from above
var parameters = ids.Select(id => new { id = id, newVal = GenerateNewValueForEachRow() }).ToArray();
IEnumerable<int> newIds = dbConnection.Query<int>(sql, parameters);
```

But I'm getting an **InvalidOperationException**: "An enumerable sequence of parameters (arrays, lists, etc) is not allowed in this context"

I have to use `Query<T>()` instead of `Execute<T>()` (or e.g. `ExecuteScalar<T>()`) because I want the `IEnumerable` of newIds. (At least, I think I have to... right?)

Further, I want to use a different `@newVal` with each row inserted, otherwise I could use

```
var parameters = new { ids = ids, newVal = GenerateNewRepeatedValue() };
```

The obvious answer is to `foreach` over `ids`:

```
// transactions and async are omitted
foreach (var id in ids)
{
    var newId = dbConnection.ExecuteScalar<int>(
        <slightly modified SQL>,
        new { id = id, newVal = GenerateNewValueForEachRow() }
    );
}
```

But I'm hoping Dapper's built-in functionality can do this for me. Can it? Thanks!